# Migrate data from one to onther table

Tags: plsql

Suppose there is one table that having one column and column name is like FULL_NAME(Rajeev Pratap Sing). However I want to insert the same data in other table that having three columns like First_Name,Middle_Name,Last_Name.

Result Should be like in other table...
**First_Name--  Middle_Name--  Last_Name**
Rajeev--      Pratap  --     Singh

Comment: So you're asking how to split a string into separate words? What should happen if there is no middle name, or two middle names?

Comment: Yes, I want to split a string into separate words.

Comment: It's extremely unlikely names will ever ALWAYS be stored as you expect.  ALWAYS expect the unexpected!  Parsing names will never work 100%.  Unless this is just an exercise, any answer should try to allow for missing elements (no first name), multiple elements (2 middle names), no/multiple/different delimiters, single quotes/spaces embedded in a name, language-specific characters in names, etc.  Of course YOU need to define the rules for how to deal with all of these situations first.  Just something to think about.

Answer (score 1):

Try below:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('Rajeev Pratap Sing','[^ ]+',1,1) "First Name",
       REGEXP_SUBSTR('Rajeev Pratap Sing','[^ ]+',1,2) "Middle Name",
       REGEXP_SUBSTR('Rajeev Pratap Sing','[^ ]+',1,3) "Last Name"
FROM DUAL
```

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO table2 
SELECT regexp_substr(full_name,'\S+'),--first name
       regexp_substr(full_name,'\S+',regexp_instr(full_name,' ',1,1)),--middle
       regexp_substr(full_name,'\S+',regexp_instr(full_name,' ',1,2)) --last
FROM table_1;
```

Comment: Thanks Prashant, I will try whit this query

Comment: I am sure .it would solve ur issue .if you find it usefull mark my answer accepted and help me earning some reputations

Comment: @RajeevSingh hi rajeev. Please rate the answer if it solved ur issue

Comment: I think you are missing a single quote in your example code, at the 3rd line. (I edited you post)

Answer (score 1):

```
Insert into emp_name(First_Name,Middle_Name,Last_Name) select 
substr(FULL_NAME,1,instr(full_name,' ')) as First_Name, 
substr(Full_Name,instr(full_name,' ',1,1)+1,instr(full_name,' ',1,2)-instr(full_name,' ',1,1)) as Middle_Name, 
substr(Full_Name,instr(full_name,' ',1,2)) as Last_Name from full_name;
```